# Accidentally set nofile & nproc for root to unlimited in /etc/security/limits.conf - Now can't login

Tags: linux, limit, ulimit

I accidentally set nofile and nproc values to unlimited and when I again tried to login, I can't login using root ssh account.

I have another user account which can login fine but root won't login... Problem is that I can't revert settings from unlimited to any other value because limits.conf is only writable by root.

Can I reboot into single user mode and try changing values? I will have to wait for off time as its production server.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Server is Vicibox 8 (openSUSE Leap 42.3)

Thanks

Comment: Boot a linux from usb key or CD, mount the filesystem, fix your files.

Comment: Thanks, is there a step by step guide for this process.. ?

Comment: Also can I boot in single user mode and edit limits.conf file to revert changes?

Comment: No worries, I was able to solve it by booting into single user mode and editing limits.conf file.
All is good now, Thanks